# Overflow:hidden dots and the end of a multiline text

Tags: html, css

I am creating a web app using ASP.NET MVC, which shows some articles to user.

And there is a summary of every article on a `div`.

Currently, I'm loading the whole content in summary `div` and set this style `overflow:hidden` for that. This is the result:

[image: Current result]

But that fragmentary line (last line) is **ugly**, also **whole content is downloading to user's computer, which is bad for speed and performance.**

I want to have something like this: (the image below is my goal)

[image: Goal]

(Remove that fragmentary text at last line, and add `...` at the end of text)

Also it is good to avoid downloading whole content to user's computer.

How to do that?

PS: Anyone know a better title for this question?!

Comment: How much text is there? Hard to believe that such text content would affect performance in any way unless you have thousands of lines of it. Also, you can't prevent the content from downloading using only HTML & CSS.

Comment: Each div contains a complete blog post. And downloading all of the latest posts is not a good idea, especially for low-speed internet connections...

Comment: Again, you need to cap the text server-side.

Comment: @Juhana Yes, but how to know how much text is needed? many fonts/languages don't have fixed-width characters. but ok, I can have a limit for text an cap it server-side. but the bigger problem is that `...` and **ugly** problem! How to solve that? (I must do that client-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your text in another div and use `height` + `line-height`

Working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DNh4W/2/

If you want to end with ellipsis there is no solution in CSS3 for multiline text. You must use javascript, for example: http://pvdspek.github.com/jquery.autoellipsis/

Example of jquery autoellipsis: http://jsfiddle.net/bdM89/1/

Comment: Sorry I put bad line-height. Check now.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I can't understand how autoellipsis jquery plugin works?

Comment: So if I use autoellipsis, I don't need to use `height` + `line-height` method??

Comment: Yes, but you are using javascript for display formatting - this is not recommended. If it is possible always use CSS for styling.

Comment: I have used autoellipsis in a generated page, but it didn't work. see this: http://www.ghiasi.net/mag/3.html#p15

Comment: You must define width and height of div.text

Comment: As you see in my page, the size of `div.text` may vary (because the title may be one line or two lines) Is there any Javascript method to determinate current automatic width and height and set it to `div.text`?

Comment: Yes look at: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/ before run autoellipsis set dimensions of `div.text` with jqeury.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a number of characters to show, then if text to show is bigger than the limit number, truncate:

```
if(text.Length > 200)
        {
            text.Substring(0, 200) + "..."; 
        }
```

Or if you are building the system, you can create a limited field to save a preview text and in listings show the preview text instead the big content

Comment: But how to know what is the limit number? many languages/fonts don't have fixed-width characters...

Comment: it's an average number, I updated my reply with other posible solution (I prefer do a preview text)

Comment: I may have a limit for the content and use your suggested method. (and correct little differences client-side) but I can't use `...` in server, because I don't know the exact needed length. Do you know any way to add `...` client-side? (using css, javascript, etc.)

Comment: _I don't know the exact needed length_ you want to fit exactly to the box? its difficult... its easiest let grow the containing div with the limit...

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll use a limit of characters. a limit that have a little more than needed text, and I'll use `rogal111`'s solution to hide that little extra content.

Answer (score 0):

if you have no problem using CSS3 in terms of browser compatibility, you can use CSS to truncate the text, like in [this tutorial](http://sharonminsuk.com/blog/2010/07/22/css3-text-truncation-and-ellipses-even-in-firefox-and-without-the-styling-constraints/):

```
.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis; /* required for Opera */
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;    /* required for IE8, allegedly */
    -moz-binding: url('ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');    /* for Firefox; details [here][2] */
}
```

Regarding mozilla firefox, [here](http://mattsnider.com/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/) is a tutorial how to deal with it using XMLs

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis` works when you have only one line of text in a block element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I believe truncating the text (to a certain number of characters) and adding the ellipsis should be done on the server side.

Then, if you want to do this using only CSS, you need to simply let the height of the div be auto. It probably won't be the same for all, but it will look nice.

Comment: I have to use fixed height (my layout don't let me have variable height...)